# how to run ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i install all ROS package but i have no idea to run any package in the terminal please help im a noob installing this software.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63888/how-to-run-ros?/) by [coughsyrup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4962/coughsyrup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-29

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-29**:
Please see the ROS tutorials

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-30**:
I would suggest that lets us not downvote such questions, rather such questions should not be allowed at answers.ros. A newbie should be encouraged to check out standard installation and tutorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hope you have installed the packages correctly. Follow this link for installation and compete basic tutorials.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to follow ROS Tutorials, on ROS website. Just go on the main page, click on **Getting started** and get a look on "Learning ROS" section.

If you installed the last ROS version, then you might have installed groovy, and not fuerte, for what this information worths

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1